# D3 move circle along path on mousemove breaks when translating line on X axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have the following plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/FLSz6swyiDuNchTYo2Xf?p=preview

Inside the plunkr you'll see that I'm trying to build a graph with 1+ paths/lines on which I'm moving some circle elements on mouse move. To accommodate the X and Y axes I need some margin. When I translate the paths/lines on X, to make room for the X axis, then the circles that move along the paths/lines aren't following the correct path anymore.

The lines are added directly to the svg element and their definition looks like this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d, i) {
            //return margin.left + xScale(i);
            return xScale(i);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return margin.top + yScale(d);
//                         return yScale(d);
        })
        .interpolate("cardinal");
```

Does anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var lines = svg.selectAll(".gLine")
   ...
```

you want to add the lines to the group you created and (correctly) translated:

```
var lines = lineGroup.selectAll(".gLine")
```

Similarly, you need to move the circles into a translated group:

```
var circles = lineGroup.selectAll("circle")
```

This "reuses" `lineGroup`, which is fine, or you can create a "circleGroup" if you'd like.

That would fix the representation, but the captured mouse coordinates would still be offset. One way to fix it is to adjust the x of the captured mouse position:

```
mouseUnderlay.on("mousemove", function () {
    var x = d3.mouse(this)[0] - margin.left;
```

[Here it is working](http://plnkr.co/edit/kHMHb8TgEHVSurJO5DXM?p=preview)

Comment: I'm trying to replace the lines on the graph with colored areas but this breaks the part which gets the SVGPoint coordinates: http://plnkr.co/edit/xdCf1YCfbVFHidAqEUmJ?p=preview Any ideas? Thanks!